# How to graph a function using TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, gnuplot

I want to plot this function with a big range says, `(-10,000:10,000)`, unfortunately I couldn't figure out how to set the `domain`, or `xrange` correctly to scale the graph nicely. This is what I have so far:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0]
    \draw[] plot[id=ff] function{
        set xrange [-10:10.5];
        plot 14*x - x**2;
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I wonder is there a simple way to draw a function with large domain? I tried some values, gnuplot always complain about the domain is too large! then how I could I draw says x = (-100, 10000)? Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you looked at `pgfplots`?

Comment: Not yet. Let me try it out. It's a bit annoying to use `gnuplot` with `tikz`. Thanks.

Comment: You should also remove your last three comments here as they are no longer relevant.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

While `tikz` can do basic graphs, you should use `pgfplots` for graphing:

[image]

As hpesoj626 commented, sometimes it is better to have the axis lines in the middle.  This also shows some of the other options that `pgfplots` provides:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0]
\begin{axis}
    \addplot[domain=-10000:10000, blue, ultra thick] {14*x - x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Code:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        axis x line=middle, 
        axis y line=middle, 
        ymax=0.1E8, ylabel=$y$, 
        xlabel=$x$
        ]
    \addplot[domain=-10000:10000, blue, ultra thick] {14*x - x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For someone who is teaching high school math, I would prefer `axis x line=middle, axis y line=middle`. But that's just me. :)

Comment: @hpesoj626L: Good point. Have used that as an excuse to illustrate some of the `pgfplots` options.

Comment: @Chan I don't want to sound nitpicky about a very big domain like you are suggesting. But when you look at the plots it appears that the vertex of the parabola is at the origin when in fact it's not. A smaller *smaller* domain like `-10:24` appears okay with me. Unless, of course, you just used the parabola `14x-x^2` as an example.

Comment: @hpesoj626: Yes, you made a good point. It was my mistake by not looking at the domain first. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @PeterGrill: I've found out that I completely ignore one of the greatest package for drawing graph. I'm excited to learn this great tool now.

Comment: I have modified your second graph to graph a polynomial with x running from -5 to 5 and y running from -10 to 10.  Along the y-axis it only labels y=5 and y=10.  How do I get it to label more y values.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126: I think it is best if you ask a new question as this question is not about adding labels. You can reference this answer as the source.  Also, apologizes for the delay in getting back to you -- had to rebuild my PC. :-(

Answer (score 6):

There is another package `tkz-fct` by Alain Matthes who is a regular in this site. (At this point though, the manual is still only in French. I just picked up the bits and pieces of code from the examples in the manual--which are a lot.) I use it once in a while to draw my graphs. Unlike `pgfplots`, `tkz-fct` requires that you have `gnuplot` installed. There is an advantage to this as Harish Kumar has already noted. You also have to invoke the `--shell-escape` option when compiling in order to draw the graph.

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth']
\tkzInit[xmin=-15,xmax=25,
         ymin=-250,ymax=50,
         xstep=5,ystep=50]
\tkzAxeXY
\tkzFct[domain=-10:24,color=blue,very thick,<->]{14*\x-\x**2}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Upon the suggestion of Peter Grill, I have done some tweaking to remove some labels to make the graph more pleasing to the eye.

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth',scale=2]
\tkzInit[xmin=-15,xmax=25,
ymin=-250,ymax=50,
xstep=10,ystep=100]
\tkzAxeXY[fill=white]
\tkzFct[domain=-10:24,color=blue,ultra thick,<->]{14*\x-\x**2}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: One minor improvement here would be to explicitly specify where the tick marks are to be placed so that you can leave out `x=15`, and `y=-50`.

Comment: @PeterGrill I don't know if that can be done in `tkz-fct` using a combination of the `\tkzInit` and `\tkzAxeXY` commands but there is always the option to use `nodes` to place the tick labels. Might ask Alain when I chance upon him in chat. I have updated my answer though by scaling the figure and changing `xstep` and `ystep`.

Comment: I did not know that. Is there something special you need to do when you run this to see the graph? I am only seeing the axis - Do see a console message: `Plot data file `<jobname>.tkzfct.table' not found.`

Comment: @PeterGrill I assume that you have `gnuplot` installed. You have to compile your file with the `--shell-escape` option.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `gnuplot` within tex in this way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0]
\begin{axis}%%[domain=-10000:10000, no markers,ultra thick]
%
\addplot[domain=-10000:10000, no markers,green,ultra thick] gnuplot{14*x - x^2};
%
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You have to use `--shell-escape` for pdftex. (I did `pdflatex --shell-escape myfile.tex`)

Advantage : `gnuplot` is better in doing calculations.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's good to know that `gnuplot` does actually have some advantages.