# tkz-fct not creating a visible graph

Tags: tkz-fct

I've tried copying a pasting code from various examples posted on this site and in the manual, but the graph is never visible.

MWE: (this MWE comes from  [this posting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78388/22413))

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth']
\tkzInit[xmin=-15,xmax=25,
         ymin=-250,ymax=50,
         xstep=5,ystep=50]
\tkzAxeXY
\tkzFct[domain=-10:24,color=blue,very thick,<->]{14*\x-\x**2}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Results in:

[image]

Comment: A couple notes that may be relevant are: I'm running TeXLive on Mac OSx.  I'm compiling the documentn using `pdflatex`.

Comment: I get the curve with latest miktex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that `tkz-fct` doesn't do the calculations itself, they are performed by Gnuplot (I think). Therefore, you need to allow for execution of external programs by compiling with the `--shell-escape` flag, i.e.

```
pdflatex -shell-escape filename.tex
```

There will be a warning in the log related to this, saying something like

```
Package pgf Warning: Plot data file `filename.tkzfct.table' not found. on input line 32.
```

The `.table` file is generated by Gnuplot, and read by `tkz-fct`, without `-shell-escape` you wont get that file.

Comment: T I'd like to thank you for this posted answer.

Comment: I just tried the latest version of MikTeX and it still doesn't work, I get the same result as the one shown in the question. I tried to add `--enable-write18` as indicated in the manual, but it didn't work. I installed gnuplot on Windows 10 and the environment variable is correct. What's going on?

Comment: @AndréC Don't know. Did you try with shell-escape? Did you look in the log file for any info? Ask a new question if you can't figure it out.

Comment: Yes, I tried your solution, without any effect on me. I have this error: `Package pgf Warning: Plot data file test-media.tkzfct.table not found. on input line 9`

Comment: @AndréC That message indicates Gnuplot wasn't run. But as I said, ask a new question and describe in detail your setup, I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: I asked a new question here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/456362/138900