# How can I make a graph of this function?

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I need to draw the function `f(x) = -5/16x^4 + 3/4x^3 + 1`, and I have no clue how to do that.

I've done something similar to what I need like this:

```
\draw[thick,color=blue] plot[samples=50, domain=-1.4:1.8] (\x,{(\x)^3-(\x)^2+1}) node[right] {$f(x) = x^3 - x^2 + 1$};
```

but it doesn't help to handle the following function.
Here is the figure which is plotted by another program.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us the code you tried so far.

Comment: Have a look at `pgfplots` (see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78383/586). And remember that you need to explicitly write the multiplication symbol, e.g. `2*x` and not `2x`.

Answer (score 1):

- Your function mentioned in code snippet differ from function shown on figure in your question. I MWE below consider the first one, however is not difficult to change it.
- In my MWE below I use package `pgfdplots` version v1.14.
- minimal `x` value is select so, that the function equation can fit in diagram.

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ticklabel style={fill=white, font=\footnotesize},
xmin=-5, xmax=3, xlabel={$x$}, xtick={-5,...,3},
ymin=-5, ymax=3, ylabel={$y$}, ytick={-5,...,3},
grid,
 axis lines=middle
]
\addplot[blue, very thick, samples=50, domain=-2:1.8] {(x)^3 -(x)^2 + 1};
\node[below right, fill=white, text=blue] at (-4,3) {$f(x) = x^3 - x^2 + 1$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

In case, that you like to have second equation, than adequately change lines `\addplot ...` and `\node ...`. You also can put axis on the top and enlarge graph width and function domain as follows:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=88mm,
ticklabel style={fill=white, inner xsep=1pt, font=\footnotesize},
xmin=-5, xmax=4, xlabel={$x$}, xtick={-5,...,4},
ymin=-5, ymax=3, ylabel={$y$}, ytick={-5,...,3},
set layers = axis on top,
axis lines = middle,
grid=both,
]
\addplot[blue, very thick, samples=50, domain=-2:4] {-5*(x^4)/16 + 3*(x^3)/4 + 1};
\node[below right, inner xsep=0pt, fill=white, text=blue] at (-5,3) 
    {$f(x) = -\frac{5}{16}x^4 + \frac{3}{4}x^3 + 1$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and the graph will become:

[image: ![enter image description here]