# Sum inside addplot call

Tags: pgfplots, pgfmath

While responding to [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/429499/graphing-truncated-fourier-transform/429501#429501) I was wondering if it was possible write for loops **inside** `addplot` calls. 
I really mean for loops inside `addplot` and not `addplot` inside `for` loop (just to make myself clear).

My answer to this post involves plotting multiple functions that are the sum of harmonics of a given frequency, which gives multiple `addplot` calls only differing by one term of the sum.

```
\addplot {sin(4*0.5*\x r)/0.5};    
\addplot {sin(4*0.5*\x r)/0.5 + sin(4*1.5*\x r)/1.5};
\addplot {sin(4*0.5*\x r)/0.5 + sin(4*1.5*\x r)/1.5 + sin(4*2.5*\x r)/2.5};
\addplot {sin(4*0.5*\x r)/0.5 + sin(4*1.5*\x r)/1.5 + sin(4*2.5*\x r)/2.5 + sin(4*3.5*\x r)/3.5};
\addplot {sin(4*0.5*\x r)/0.5 + sin(4*1.5*\x r)/1.5 + sin(4*2.5*\x r)/2.5 + sin(4*3.5*\x r)/3.5 + sin(4*4.5*\x r)/4.5};
\addplot {sin(4*0.5*\x r)/0.5 + sin(4*1.5*\x r)/1.5 + sin(4*2.5*\x r)/2.5 + sin(4*3.5*\x r)/3.5 + sin(4*4.5*\x r)/4.5 + sin(4*5.5*\x r)/5.5};
```

I don't think this is quite elegant, and I was wondering if there was a way to avoid this using something like

```
\addplot {sum[nmin,nmax,n](sin(\n*0.5*\x r)/0.5)};
```

where `nmin`/`nmax` would be the starting/ending indexes of the sum. 
This question could be generalized to products or other for loops.

Here is the MWE to test this

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}
\pgfplotsset{cycle list/Reds-6}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
    width=\textwidth,
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=left,cycle multi list={Reds-6}]
    \addplot+[samples=300,smooth] {sin(4*0.5*\x r)/0.5};    
    \addplot+[samples=300,smooth] {sin(4*0.5*\x r)/0.5 + sin(4*1.5*\x r)/1.5};
    \addplot+[samples=300,smooth] {sin(4*0.5*\x r)/0.5 + sin(4*1.5*\x r)/1.5 + sin(4*2.5*\x r)/2.5};
    \addplot+[samples=300,smooth] {sin(4*0.5*\x r)/0.5 + sin(4*1.5*\x r)/1.5 + sin(4*2.5*\x r)/2.5 + sin(4*3.5*\x r)/3.5};
    \addplot+[samples=300,smooth] {sin(4*0.5*\x r)/0.5 + sin(4*1.5*\x r)/1.5 + sin(4*2.5*\x r)/2.5 + sin(4*3.5*\x r)/3.5 + sin(4*4.5*\x r)/4.5};
    \addplot+[samples=300,smooth] {sin(4*0.5*\x r)/0.5 + sin(4*1.5*\x r)/1.5 + sin(4*2.5*\x r)/2.5 + sin(4*3.5*\x r)/3.5 + sin(4*4.5*\x r)/4.5 + sin(4*5.5*\x r)/5.5};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `tikzmath` to define the function

Comment: @percusse thanks, i will have a look into that

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I set up a  stencil and used `listofitems` to parse it for `?` via

```
\readlist\termstencil{sin(4*?.5*\x r)/?.5}
```

Then, substitute for `?` each time through the loop, a value of `0`, then `1`, ..., `5`.  A few checks had to be made not to add a `+` before the first term, etc.  The resulting tokens are collected into the macro `\myeqn`, which is then passed to `\addplot`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}
\pgfplotsset{cycle list/Reds-6}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\loopthroughterm[1]{%
  \def\myeqn{}%
  \foreach\z in{0,...,#1}{%
    \ifnum\z=0\relax\else\g@addto@macro\myeqn{+}\fi%
    \foreachitem\zz\in\termstencil[]{%
      \ifnum\zzcnt=1\else%
        \expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter\myeqn\expandafter{\z}\fi%
      \expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter\myeqn\expandafter{\zz}%
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
    width=\textwidth,
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=left,cycle multi list={Reds-6}]
    \setsepchar{?}
    \readlist\termstencil{sin(4*?.5*\x r)/?.5}
    \foreach\k in{0,...,5}{
      \loopthroughterm{\k}
      \addplot+[samples=300,smooth] {\myeqn};
    }
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Upon exiting the `tikzpicture`, one can `\detokenize\expandafter{\myeqn}` to confirm the tokens themselves used for the final loop index:

[image]

---

**ADDENDUM**

Seeing jbfu's use of a helper macro, I realized I could use the same concept to dispense with the `listofitems` approach, and not use another package in its place.

Basically, I get the `\loopthroughterm` macro to create a succession of tokens of the form `\termstencil{0}+\termstencil{1}+\termstencil{2}...`.  Then, as long as `\termstencil` is defined by the user properly, in this case as

```
\def\termstencil#1{sin(4*#1.5*\x r)/#1.5}
```

then all works out in the end.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}
\pgfplotsset{cycle list/Reds-6}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\loopthroughterm[1]{%
  \def\myeqn{}%
  \foreach\z in{0,...,#1}{%
    \ifnum\z=0\relax\else\g@addto@macro\myeqn{+}\fi%
    \expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter\myeqn\expandafter{%
      \expandafter\termstencil\expandafter{\z}}%
  }%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
    width=\textwidth,
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=left,cycle multi list={Reds-6}]
    \def\termstencil#1{sin(4*#1.5*\x r)/#1.5}
    \foreach\k in{0,...,5}{
      \loopthroughterm{\k}
      \addplot+[samples=300,smooth] {\myeqn};
    }
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The plot is the same as in the prior code, but the detokenized form of `\myeqn` is now this:

[image]

Additionally, with the use of a few extra `\expandafter`s, in the form of

```
\newcommand\loopthroughterm[1]{%
  \def\myeqn{}%
  \foreach\z in{0,...,#1}{%
    \ifnum\z=0\relax\else\g@addto@macro\myeqn{+}\fi%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter%
      \expandafter\expandafter\myeqn\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
        \expandafter\termstencil\expandafter{\z}}%
  }%
}
```

the final `\myeqn` now contains the actual tokens desired:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Here is with `xinttools`. I suspect (but did not check) unexpandable loop could not be used inside `\addplot` argument, so I defined preliminary macro `\myterm` to use with the expandable utilities `\xintApply` and `\xintListWithSep`.

The external `\xintFor` is not expandable, and dispense us of any preliminary macro definition.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}
\pgfplotsset{cycle list/Reds-6}
\usepackage{xinttools}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\myterm#1{sin(4*#1.5*\x r)/#1.5}
\begin{axis}[%
    width=\textwidth,
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=left,cycle multi list={Reds-6}]
    \xintFor #1 in {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5} \do 
    {%    
    \addplot+[samples=300,smooth] 
     {\xintListWithSep{+}{\xintApply\myterm{\xintSeq{0}{#1}}}}; 
    }   
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]