# Strange steps on a 3D plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, 3d

**Problematic**

Thanks to schrodinger's cat [visualizing-a-function-defined-through-a-summation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/526585/visualizing-a-function-defined-through-a-summation), I adapted his answer to display the value of a bond security that pays a fix amount (Coupon `\C`) over a certain amount of time. It's the equation in the title of the plot.

**Questions**

When I try do display the DF function `DF(\n,\r)=pow((1+\r),-\n)` it's smooth.

Why do I get this strange wavelet when I introduce the sum ?

[image]

[image]

MWE

```
\documentclass[tikz,export,fleqn]{standalone}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\newcounter{isum}
\pgfplotsset{summand/.initial=max}
%-------- On définit la somme   ----------------  
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{sum}{2}{%
\begingroup%
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}%
\edef\myfun{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/summand}}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mysum}{0}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myx}{#2}%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\imax}{#1}%
\setcounter{isum}{1}%
\loop
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mysum}{\mysum+\myfun(\value{isum},#2)}%
\ifnum\value{isum}<\imax\relax
\stepcounter{isum}\repeat
\pgfmathparse{\mysum}%
\pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult\endgroup%
}%
\begin{document}

%Different levels of \C, they represent percentage to a dollar
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0.01,0.02,...,0.04}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}[
            declare function={DF(\n,\r)=pow((1+\r),-\n);},
            ]
            \begin{axis}[
            xlabel=Rates,
            ylabel=Time to Maturity,
            zlabel=Bond value,,             
            title={$P=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{#1}{(1+r)^{k}}+\frac{1}{(1+r)^{n}}$},
                    domain=0.0:0.05,    % Interest rates
                    y domain=0:10,  % Maturity
                    view={30}{20},
                ]

\def\C{0.05}
    \addplot3[summand=DF,surf]  {#1*sum(y,x)+ DF(y,x)};
%   \addplot3[summand=DF,surf]  {\C*sum(y,x)+ DF(y,x)};
%   \addplot3[summand=DF,surf]  {DF(y,x)};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \end{document}
```

Comment: The answer is very simple, I think. You plot `#1*sum(y,x)+ DF(y,x)` where `#1` is a constant. The `sum(y,x)` evaluates to a sum over `i` from 1 to `int(y)` over `DF(i,x)`. Clearly, `int(y)` has steps. I think that if you explain what you *really* want to plot it will be possible to make this happen.

Comment: Off-topic, wavelets are a very specific type of signals :) . So these are much more *steps* than *wavelets*.

Comment: I changed the title.

Comment: Did you have a look at Schrödinger's cat comment ?

Comment: Yes ! Working on it right now.

Comment: Note that if you want to address a user or let him know you answered, you need to point this user using an `@` call. In your case, as this is your question, you are automatically pinged for any activity so we do not have to do it.

Comment: Sure will do ! :)

Comment: Any news ??????

Comment: @BambOo locked home with a toddler, i can hardly seat 5 mins in peace :) Schrodinger's cat is right, I use maturity as an integer not as an y varying continuously.

Comment: @BambOo  @Schrodinger's cat showed me I was using wrongly an integer parameter (`n`) to pass it as a real number (`y`). Shall we close this question ?

Comment: @BambOo just found https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/455721/how-to-pass-an-array-to-function-in-pgfmathdeclarefunction that I need to study.

Comment: @Julien-ElieTaieb, I asked a while ago how to handle sums inside addplots, not totally sure this could help but maybe you should have a look https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/429508/sum-inside-addplot-call

Comment: @BambOo, thank you i'll look at it !

Comment: @JeT, why did you remove the `3d` tag from the question (I added earlier)? Having these tags helps me filtering when I am searching for duplicates.

Comment: @StefanPinnow my bad ! I put it back :)

Comment: @JeT, many thanks :)